# How to de-serialize the following file to generic type variables using Jackson streaming API

Tags: java, jackson

I have a question about how to de-serialize the following file to generic type variables using Jackson streaming API.

```
{ “key1”: {“value”:{…} },
  “key2”: {“value”:{…} },
  “key3”: {“value”:{…}}
}
```

I had some code which de-serialize the whole file using:

```
Map<K, ValueClass<V>> map = mapper.readValue(new File(fileName), someTypeReferForMapFunc ());
then store to a HashMap using put (omit here)
```

where mapper is ObjectMapper.

The file is large. to reduce memory, I changed the code as follows using Jackson streaming API:

```
private HashMap<K, ValueClass<V>> loadFileUsingStreamAPI(String fileName){
    JsonFactory f = new MappingJsonFactory();     
    JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(new File(fileName));
    JsonToken current;
    HashMap<K, ValueClass<V>> kvmap = new HashMap(...);
    current = jp.nextToken();     
    if (current != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {            
        System.out.println("Error: root should be object: quiting.");          
        return;     
    }
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {       
        String key = jp.getCurrentName();   (1)
        current = jp.nextToken();
        if (current == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            ValueClass val = mapper.readValue (jp, ValueClass.class);
            Kvmap.put(key, val); //(2)
        }
        else {skip to next object...}
    }
    return Kvmap;
}
```

However, compile fails at line (2) because key should be K not String. I tried to change line (1) as:

```
K key = (K)jp.readValueAs(String.class);
```

Still failed. Does anybody know how can I read key as type K so that I can put K key to Kvmap?

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm, from your question is unclear, what is `K` class, the class for Map keys, if it's not a String. An enum?

Comment: the generic class for Map keys. just like the K in HashMap<K, V>. It can be any type.

Comment: Well, do you understand that a generic is a placeholder? You can't instantiate "a generic", you always need a particular class, if you need an instance.

Comment: Certainly, some _methods_ which handle data could be generic. So such methods receive generic arguments. But to instantiate an object one should decide what type it is.

Comment: When you write `jp.readValueAs(AClass.class)`, you instruct Jackson to instantiate that partucular class (or a class reflecting AClass if the latter is an interface), and fill it with data from Json stream.

Comment: Well, it seems that your example code should include the signature of the method from which the deserializing code is extracted. Perhaps I could imagine what is your actual problem

Comment: I tried to call JavaType keyType = TypeFactory.type(k);
Class<?> keyCls = keyType.getRawClass(); to get the class of K, then call K key = (K)jp.readValueAs(keyCls); but failed compile, so I tried K key = (K)jp.readValueAs(String.class) as a start, still failed. the failure message said it is not compatible with JSONToken.FIELD_NAME.

Comment: I know what generic is. when the code runs, the actual type will pass to replace K and V and be used. But here, I have trouble to get K. I was thinking of calling K key = (K)jp.readValueAs(keyCls) to get key. Note that if I call String key = jp.getCurrentName(); then I have no problem to get val: ValueClass val = mapper.readValue (jp, ValueClass.class); then why I could not get K key = (K)jp.readValueAs(keyCls)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67262/discussion-between-user389955-and-user3159253).

Comment: Why do you want the keys are of type K? If they are keys of a json map they must be Strings, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but when the type of key I want to serialize and de-serilize IS a generic type, although in reality it is String. In fact, I have found a way: after getting String keyStr = jp.getCurrentName(), create a another string jsonStr = "{\"key\":\"" + KeyStr + "\"}"; and then User user = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, User.class);K key = (K)user.key; besides, I have to define a classUser<K> {public K key}.